# I want to install vim with ruby support on Ubuntu 15.04 vivid vervet

Tags: vim, ruby

I have installed Ubuntu 15.04 and am trying to set up my Ruby on Rails environment to program.

I use vim as the IDE and it comes pre-installed without ruby support:

```
vim --version | grep -i ruby
```

returns the following:

```
+diff            +menu            -ruby            +writebackup
```

Ruby should be +ruby not -ruby.

Since Ubuntu 15.04 has been out for not to long there isn't much out there.

Would appreciate anyone pointing me in the right direction.

Cheers!

Comment: what vim package do you have installed ? I have vim-gnome and it comes with ruby support.

Comment: I have the vim that come with the standard install just vim...

Comment: Just want to confirm that I removed vim installed vim-gnome and executed vim --version | grep -i ruby and it returned +ruby so I am good to go. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

OP solved own problem (see comment) by installing vim-gnome:

> Just want to confirm that I removed vim installed `vim-gnome` and executed `vim --version | grep -i ruby` and it returned `+ruby` so I am good to go.